# Python Django: RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.sites.models.Site (error goes on)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm currently writing a web-application with Python Django.
My problem is, that i recently installed django-relationships,
added it to my INSTALLED_APPS inside the settings.py.

Since then I'm getting this wired error and I have NO Idea what it means.

Somebody out there can help me?

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x10c6fdcf8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Maximilian_H/Documents/SkyPixelServernetzwerk/Coding-Projects/Website/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Maximilian_H/Documents/SkyPixelServernetzwerk/Coding-Projects/Website/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/Maximilian_H/Documents/SkyPixelServernetzwerk/Coding-Projects/Website/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/Users/Maximilian_H/Documents/SkyPixelServernetzwerk/Coding-Projects/Website/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Maximilian_H/Documents/SkyPixelServernetzwerk/Coding-Projects/Website/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", 
line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/Maximilian_H/Documents/SkyPixelServernetzwerk/Coding-Projects/Website/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Users/Maximilian_H/Documents/SkyPixelServernetzwerk/Coding-Projects/Website/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/Maximilian_H/Documents/SkyPixelServernetzwerk/Coding-Projects/Website/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/relationships/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
  File "/Users/Maximilian_H/Documents/SkyPixelServernetzwerk/Coding-Projects/Website/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py", line 83, in <module>
    class Site(models.Model):
  File "/Users/Maximilian_H/Documents/SkyPixelServernetzwerk/Coding-Projects/Website/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 102, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.sites.models.Site doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `django-relationships` depends on the `Site` model. You must add `django.contrib.sites` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` as well.

The second error indicates that `django-relationships` tries to import `create_many_related_manager` from `django.db.models.fields.related`. This function was removed in Django 1.9. If a newer version is available, you can try if that works. If not, `django-relationships` is not usable with Django 1.9.

Comment: @Red_C0der Stackoverflow is perfectly capable of handling code and tracebacks. Please paste in your question rather than using an external site.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. (I'm new here)

Answer (score 0):

add `django.contrib.sites` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`  and `SITE_ID = 1` in your settings.py that solved my problem